# MediaMetadataRetriever.getFramesAtIndex(int, int) not being resolved by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-bitmap

Trying to use the `MediaMetadataRetriever.getFramesAtIndex(int, int)` method but it isn't being resolved in Android Studio. Is there any other way to get all the frames from a video as a `List<Bitmap>`?